# C++ std::auto_ptr copy constructor

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

std::auto_ptr lacks const copy constructor, therefore I cannot use it directly in collections.  is there some way to have for example vector of std::auto_ptr without using boost pointer collection template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a C++0x compiler you can use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` as appropriate.

There is a good example of correct `unique_ptr` usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/push-back-of-unique-ptr) courtesy of @James McNellis. For a `shared_ptr` walkthrough look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476938/example-to-use-shared-ptr), courtesy of @D.Shawley. [Upvotes would still be appreciated on those threads, I am sure.]

`vector` of `auto_ptr` is always invalid, although Visual C++ v6 disagreed.

Comment: `shared_ptr` does not require C++0x; it is in TR1.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - thanks for the clarifying note - `unique_ptr` is a better fit to correct flawed `auto_ptr` semantics if OP has access to it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you just can't have a vector of `std::auto_ptr`, though there exist many speculations that you can. But if your compiler supports C++0x, you can use `std::unique_ptr`, which is the new alternative of the deprecated auto pointer which, quote from the new standard, provides a superior alternative. See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/push-back-of-unique-ptr)

Answer (score 1):

auto_ptr is designed for auto deletion when a variable leaves scope.  You don't want to use it in a collection, instead as mentioned above you want to use something like shared_ptr.

Example of auto_ptr's typical use:

```
void foo()
{
   auto_ptr<int> bar = auto_ptr<int>(new int);
   ...

   return;  //memory held by auto_ptr is automatically deleted
}
```

Anything beyond this use is potentially dangerous and/or broken if you are not sure of the special semantics of auto_ptr. (Edit: clarify based on Armen's comment)

Comment: I would argue with your statement "Anything beyond this use is probably dangerous and/or broken"...

Comment: Fair enough, there are other valid uses.  Though auto_ptr's uses are relatively limited and it can be rather dangerous if you use it outside of a constrained scope, like as a local variable in a function.