# How can I destroy a shared object safely in a multi-threaded program?

Tags: c++

I designed some class. It's like this:

1. The class `ClientEntity` can have multiple instances.
2. When a `ClientEntity` object is created, it will not be modified, so I don't use the mutex.
3. `ClientEntity` objects can be accessed between different threads.
4. `ClientEntity` objects will be destroyed when they receive some quit commands.
5. `ClientEntity` objects may be accessed by some threads.

**How can I destroy this object safely?**

```
class ClientEntity
{
public:
    conference_info & conf_info (){return conf_info_;}
    void conf_info(const conference_info &ci){conf_info_ = ci;}

    user_info & usr_info(){return usr_info_;}
    void usr_info(const user_info &ui){usr_info_ = ui;}

private:
    web_conf_info *wci_;
    user_info usr_info_;
    conference_info conf_info_;

    // .....
};

class user_info
{
public:
    user_info & operator = (const user_info &ui)
    {   
        if (this != &ui){
            user_id = ui.user_id;
            user_name = ui.user_name;
            user_role = ui.user_role;
        }   

        return *this;
    }   
public:
    int user_id;
    int user_role;
    std::string user_name;
};


class conference_info
{
public:
    conference_info & operator = (const conference_info &conf)
    {   
        if (this != &conf){
            conf_id = conf.conf_id;
            dtsip_list = conf.dtsip_list;
            ctsip_list = conf.ctsip_list;
        }   

        return *this;
    }
public:
    int conf_id;
    std::list<std::string> dtsip_list;
    std::list<std::string> ctsip_list;
};
```

Comment: By the very definition of your posted usage case, the only way to "safely" destroy the object is to ensure no usage can/will happen for that specific instance again. I.e. no thread has an outstanding finger in the pie before you eat it.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is your friend. Alternatively, if the objects aren't too large, and immutable (ie. cannot be modified as you put it), make copies of them.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to determine that you can (or can't) delete a shared object is to use reference counting - either by use of a "shared pointer", or as part of your own logic in the class itself. You will have to have some sort of function that is used by the client code to say "I want to use this object", that increments the reference count. When the client is finished, it calls the "I'm no longer interested in this object" and the reference count is counted down. If reference count becomes zero (and the object isn't needed for other reasons) it can be deleted.

Comment: Do you have some other solutions?

Comment: What particular aspect isn't good with my suggested solution? It's good enough for virtual memory pages in the Linux operating system, and is commonly used for graphics solutions (e.g. textures and surfaces in OpenGL and similar).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest when creating the `ClientEntity` object, you should make sure it is correctly owned by another object, say a global object, and when the global object get destroyed, delete the `ClientEntity`.

Of course you can delete the `ClientEntity` at any time between multiple threads, but when you are trying to delete the `ClientEntity`, use synchronization object like critical section.

Other threads that access the `ClientEntity` should use critical section etc also, to prevent the object gets deleted when it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I have used my own classes which do reference counting.  And I did a search and found that this could be used:

[Example to use shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476938/example-to-use-shared-ptr)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm