# C++ allocating shared_ptr with C++11 (std::shared_ptr): Is it still bad to initialize the shared_ptr into a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477305/340947) and the author refers to [boost best practices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices) which says:

> Avoid using unnamed shared_ptr temporaries to save typing; to see why
>   this is dangerous, consider this example:

```
void f(shared_ptr<int>, int); 
int g();

void ok() {
    shared_ptr<int> p(new int(2));
    f(p, g());
}

void bad() {
    f(shared_ptr<int>(new int(2)), g());
}
```

> The function ok follows the guideline to the letter, whereas bad constructs the temporary
>   shared_ptr in place, admitting the possibility of a memory leak. Since
>   function arguments are evaluated in unspecified order, it is possible
>   for new int(2) to be evaluated first, g() second, and we may never get
>   to the shared_ptr constructor if g throws an exception. <...>
>
> The exception safety problem described above may also be eliminated by
>   using the make_shared or allocate_shared factory functions defined in
>   boost/make_shared.hpp. These factory functions also provide an
>   efficiency benefit by consolidating allocations.

I guess I will start using `make_shared`, but I was wondering if this bit of advice still applies to C++11 `shared_ptr`. I ask because I don't really fully understand why it is that a throwing `g()` would prevent the ctor from getting called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, C++11's `shared_ptr` works the same way.

> I ask because I don't really fully understand why it is that a throwing g() would prevent the ctor from getting called.

What aren't you understanding? It's an order of operations problem, and the standard doesn't *require* a specific order. Let's unpack the statement into a sequence of expressions:

```
auto __temp = new int(2);
auto &&__temp2 = g();
auto __temp3 = shared_ptr<int>(__temp);
```

Do you see the problem now? If `g` throws, then `__temp3` will never be initialized. Therefore, `__temp` will be *leaked*.

The C++ standard does not require that the statement be unpacked in this way. But it does not *forbid it* either. The compiler is allowed the freedom to order these independent expressions however it sees fit.

Comment: I couldn't ask for a better explanation, it's just really unexpected (to me) that the "unpacking order" of something like this would not always be the same. Also, I still have not had a chance to gain a proper understanding of rvalue references.

Comment: @StevenLu: rvalue references have nothing to do with that. I just used the `auto&&` to capture the result of `g()` so that it could be properly forwarded when it came time to call the function. It has nothing to do with the ordering of the operations. Also, the order will probably be the same... just not *across* compilers.

Comment: Ah. See, I saw the `&&`, knew it was "that thing I don't understand yet", so I didn't investigate further. But I see now that this (pseudo)code is illustrating how it is possible that the compiler could produce code which constructs `g()` **after** allocating the int, and also that the first two lines could be in the opposite order (in which case things would be fine).

Comment: I understand that the order of evaluation of function arguments is undefined, but once the compiler decied to evaluate the first argument and thus the `shared_ptr` constructor, doesn't it have to follow it through till the end (i.e. only try to evaluate the `new` as part of the constructor evaluation). Does the undefined evaluation order really carry through multiple hierarchies of nested function calls?

Comment: @ChristianRau - my thoughts exactly...I guess I need to reread http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Comment: @ChristianRau, it does not have to, in the sense that the Standard does not say it has to anywhere. What is required is given by 1.9[#15].

Comment: @ChristianRau: "*Does the undefined evaluation order really carry through multiple hierarchies of nested function calls?*" Yes. This is about expression evaluation order. And because the two terms of the expressions are not sequenced to happen before each other, they can happen in any order.

Comment: @NicolBolas Actually, a single compiler could reorder it differently for optimization purposes.  Or, if the compiler could prove that the code has no resource contention, actually execute it in parallel (I don't think any compiler/architecture does this?).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anything has changed with respect to the order of evaluation in C++11. That is, using `std::make_shared<T>(...)` is the better option with respect to safety in addition to requiring only one memory allocation rather than two.

With respect to what the problem: the following evaluation of `f()` argument is perfectly valid:

1. `$tmp = new int(1)` (using `$tmp` to indicate a compiler provided, temporary variable)
2. `g()`
3. `std::shared_ptr<int>($tmp)`

Now, if `g()` throws, the evaluation of the other parts is never executed, i.e., the `std::shared_ptr<int>` is never constructed and `$tmp` is leaked.