# C++: Array of parent and child objects

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I am designing a game in which some players cards are known and some aren't. To do this, I made a parent object "Player" with children "OpenPlayer" and "ClosedPlayer".

I want to make an array of all the players in this game to facilitate game management. However, I also want to be able to access the special methods in OpenPlayer and ClosedPlayer as appropriate. Is this possible?

Edit: I am actually thinking of using a vector from STL as this would likely be more appropriate due to variable number of players.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475030/different-types-of-objects-in-the-same-vector-array (especially look at Anthony Williams' answer and replace 'gate' with 'player'). Also, this is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274136/objects-of-different-classes-in-a-single-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't make a C++ array whose elements are of different class types; each array element must be the same size, and that won't necessarily be true of different subclasses. Putting different types in the the array can result in *slicing*, which is the surprising disappearance of the data members of a subclass.

But if you make an array of *pointers* to your different subclasses, then you'll easily be able to do what you want. You might also consider using a `vector` instead of an array if the number of players can vary.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of using pointers. That's a great idea, thank you. If I make it a vector of "Player", will I be able to have it refer to both Open and Closed player? Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to C++.

Comment: A `vector<Player*>` would work; a plain `vector<Player>` would also suffer from the slicing problem.

Comment: I got it working with the `vector`, however I need to access some none virtual methods. Casting seems to work fine, but how can I tell which child to cast to? I tried comparing the typeid but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: That would be the way; maybe tell us what goes wrong exactly, and we could figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Whenever I was trying typeid, it just gave me `Player*` as the type, so I had no idea what to cast to. I realized I can just use dyanmic_cast. That seems to be working for me. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: You'd want to look at `typeid( *theVector[i] )` -- i.e., you want the `typeid` of what the pointer is pointing *to*, not of the pointer itself. Once you have that, then you can `dynamic_cast<>` to the right type.

Answer (score 0):

By "access special methods" I assume you mean methods in just the OpenPlayer or just the ClosedPlayer?

By array, I assume you mean some STL collection ;-)

The short answer is "No".

The long answer is "Yes you can, but you'll need to cast objects to the correct type. This implies that your design is wrong."

A different disign might be to make "Open" or "Closed" a property of the Player class rather than individual subclasses.